# VBA FileSystemObject Sorting Files in Incorrect Order - Need Help to Maintain Original File Sequence

Tags: vba, file, ms-word, filenames

I have a VBA script that uses the FileSystemObject to work with files in a folder. The issue I'm facing is that FSO is sorting the files in an wrong order, such as:

1,
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
2,
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
and so on.

I'd like the script to consider the files in their original sequence, i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and so on, without using leading zeros. How can I achieve this without altering the file naming convention in the folder?

is there any better way of doing this?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim FileItem As Object
    Dim TempDoc As Document
    Dim FileList() As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set TempDoc = ActiveDocument
    FolderPath = TempDoc.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim Col As Collection
    Dim NotNum As Collection
    
    ' Iterate through folders and files
    For Each Folder In FileSystem.GetFolder(FolderPath).Subfolders
        
        Set Col = New Collection
        Set NotNum = New Collection

        For Each FileItem In Folder.Files
            FileName = FileItem.Name

            If InStr(FileName, "-") > 0 Then
                Dim parts() As String
                parts = Split(FileName, "-")
                If IsNumeric(parts(0)) Then
                    Col.Add Array(CLng(parts(0)), FileName)
                Else
                    NotNum.Add Array("", FileName)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    
    ' Sort the numeric collection based on the first number
    bubbleSort Col
    
    'Combined with Not Numeric
    For i = 1 To NotNum.Count
        Col.Add Array(NotNum(i)(0), NotNum(i)(1))
    Next i
        
    ' Loop through the sorted collection and process the files
    For i = 1 To Col.Count
        Debug.Print Col(i)(0); Col(i)(1) ' Change this to your processing logic
    Next i
    
    Next
    
End Sub
Sub bubbleSort(cFruit As Collection)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim vTemp As Variant
Dim vItm As Variant

    'Two loops to bubble sort
    For i = 1 To cFruit.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To cFruit.Count
        
            If cFruit(i)(0) > cFruit(j)(0) Then
                'store the lesser item
                vTemp = cFruit(j)
                'remove the lesser item
                cFruit.Remove j
                're-add the lesser item before the greater Item
                cFruit.Add Array(vTemp(0), vTemp(1)), Before:=i
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you think there is an "original sequence" to the file order?

Comment: Returning the file names in the Immediate window isn't particularly useful. What are you planning to do with the list or the files? Are the numbers the full (base)names of the files e.g. `1.docx`?

Comment: @GSerg, sorry I should say Natural Number sequence

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes! the file has only numbers, but I do not know the total count of files as well as what should be the file name of the last file.

Comment: You could use the `Dictionary` (part of the same library as fso) to write the numbers to its keys and the names (paths) to its items e.g. `fName = FileItem.Name: dict(Val(fname)) = fName`. When the loop is done, then to array: `Arr = dict.Keys`. Then sort the array in place, e.g. `BubbleSort Arr`, and write the names to the array: `For n = LBound(arr) To UBound(Arr): Arr(n) = dict(Arr(n)): Next n`. You can probably manage to adapt (use as-is) the various bubble sort procedures (implementations) found all over the net.

Comment: The sequence you present is perfectly correct when sorting strings.  If you want a natural number sequence then you must first convert the string to longs (for example).  Useful  sort algorithms can be found here.   https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?473677-VB6-Sorting-algorithms-%28sort-array-sorting-arrays%29

Comment: @freeflow You probably didn't notice `Val(fName)` which retrieves a number, not a string.

Comment: I was referring to the original post.

Comment: @all Added Updated VBA code

Comment: Possibly could use the mscorlib.SortedList.